# Can't load URL:The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains in react-native

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, facebook-login

I'am integrating social login in my react-native application.Error message is

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
> [image]

How to integrate oAuth facebook login in react-native application ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to head down to `Settings` > `Advanced` and under `Domain Manager` to add your domain name there.

[image]